# What types to use for my numbers when calculating

Tags: java

So I need to calculate a value.

The input I get is this:

```
a is seed/m2.  The value might a for example 56 but it might be 56.7 also.
b is in g's. for instance 600g
c is % value, might be 90.6 also
d is % value, might be 90.6 also
```

The result I get should be as `kg/ha`
Regular int does not cut it. The value of `(56 * 600 / 100 / 100) / 100`
will be `0.0336`. I could multiply it with 10000 but I would lose the precision.

I also tried BigDecimal for this but it gave me a `ArithmeticException: “Non-terminating decimal expansion; no exact representable decimal result”` when I changed the values of my % variables to something else than 100.

What would be the best option to go with this? The calculation was easy to do in exel as it knew how to convert each value automatically, but doing it in Java code is another thing.

My solutions:

int version:

```
int a = Integer.decode(germinativeSeed.getText().toString());
            int b = Integer.decode(seedMass.getText().toString());
            int c = Integer.decode(clean.getText().toString());
            int d = Integer.decode(germinative.getText().toString());

            int result2 = ( a * b / c / d) / 100;
```

result is 0

BigDecimal solution:

```
BigDecimal result2;

            BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal(germinativeSeed.getText().toString());
            BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(seedMass.getText().toString());

            BigDecimal c;
            BigDecimal d;

            if (clean.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                c = new BigDecimal("100");
            } else {
                c = new BigDecimal(clean.getText().toString());
            }

            if (germinative.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                d = new BigDecimal("100");
            } else {
                d = new BigDecimal(germinative.getText().toString());
            }

            BigDecimal hundred = new BigDecimal("100");
            BigDecimal test = new BigDecimal("10000");

            result2 = a.multiply(b);
            result2 = result2.divide(c, 2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
            result2 = result2.divide(d, 2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
            result2 = result2.divide(hundred, 2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
            result2 = result2.multiply(test);
```

Result is correct with this only if % values are 100%.

Comment: Added my current solutions.

Comment: why `Integer.decode`?  I suggest you debug or log your  variables after reading the values from string to ensure that you're reading the right values.

Comment: Well I had a string and had to make it into int.

Comment: if your string is really an int, `Integer.decode` isn't the way to go, `Integer.parseInt` is a less complicated choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
double seed = (double) seedInput;
double m2 = (double) m2Input;
double b = (double) bInput; // unit 'g' is not relevant
double c = (double) cInput;
double d = (double) dInput;
double a = seed / m2;
int result2 = ( a * b / c / d) / 100.0;
```

So I converted everything to double so you won't have problems with implicit conversions to int.

Comment: Trying it out. Will let you know of results.

Comment: That seemed to work! Will accept your answer when the timer ends.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem comes when you have rational numbers like 1/3, this cannot be represented in a bigdecimal, as it has an infinite representation.

If you really need very big precision you should crate a new bigrational class, where you would store a nominator and denominator, and calculate with them. The code would be much mode complicated.

If you don't need that go for doubles.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `float` or `double` (preferred `double` because of the precision).